# Using surround query for multi words with their synonyms in solr 4

Tags: solr

i am using solr 4.0, can solr support surround query with multi tokens? like: q=Filed:{!surround}(aa OR syn1) 4w (cc OR syn2) ?
If not how to run multi surround query for multi synonyms words in the query? (I using PreAnalyzedField, i use json format with tokens positions information to index the field)
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If using edismax is no problem you can check out https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms for multi word synonyms.